# Prevent Javascript from creating dates with a large months

Tags: javascript, date

In Javascript if I create a date like so:

```
var y=new Date('2014','16','06')
```

Then `y` will be on my computer `Wed May 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400`. However, the month I entered is `16` not `5`. Is there anyway to prevent Javascript from creating a valid date in this instance (when Month is too big) and just return 'Invalid Date'?

Comment: No, unless you check the parameters first

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant information from the Mozilla Javascript documentation for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one
>   argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is
>   provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent
>   value will be adjusted. E.g.  new Date(2013,13,1) is equivalent to new
>   Date(2014,1,1), both create a date for 2014-02-01 (note that the month
>   is 0-based).  Similarly for other values: new Date(2013,2,1,0,70) is
>   equivalent to new Date(2013,2,1,1,10) which both create a date for
>   2013-03-01T01:10:00.

So in answer, no, that's the only behavior of the Date constructor, and any validation you want to do on your input values is going to have to be done by you before you pass them into the constructor.

However, one possible option could be to concatenate a string of your date value and then use `Date.parse()` on it, which will return a valid value if your date is correct or `NaN` if it isn't.